# увеличение ширины при прокрутке вниз

Tags: jquery, css

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop) {
       $( window ).scroll(function() {
           $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "+=1px");  
       });
   } else {
       $( window ).scroll(function() {
           $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "+=-1px");  
       });
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

состряпал из примеров вот такой код. по идеи он должен увеличивать ширину при прокрутке вниз и уменьшать при прокрутке вверх. но по факту только увеличивает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "+=-1px");  скорее всего надо заменить на            $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "-=1px");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот я немного поменял код и уже нормально работает, только здесь для наглядности меняю высотку каждый раз не на `1px` а на `5px`.

```js
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll', function(event) {
       var curWidth = parseInt($(".baloon1 img").css("width"));
       delta = parseInt(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail);
       if (delta <= 0) {
           $( window ).scroll(function() {
               $(".baloon1 img").css("width", (curWidth+5)+"px");  
           });
       } else {
           $( window ).scroll(function() {
               $(".baloon1 img").css("width", (curWidth-5)+"px");  
           });
       }
    });
```

```css
.baloon1{
      height: 600px;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="baloon1">
      <img src="https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/8/005/05c/36c/14dce05.jpg" width="400" />
    </div>
```

Comment: можно вопрос, вроде по сути код тот же самый же, что именно не воспринималось в моем? и главное почему

Comment: @PaulWall `$(".baloon1 img").css("width", "+=-1px");`

Comment: я менял на =-1px и на -=1px толку 0